# Foundation Section (Tabs) not reflowing properly

Tags: html, backbone.js, zurb-foundation

I have two Tab Sections on my site that are being added after page load. I am "reflowing" them through `backbone.js` like this:

```
this.$el.foundation('section', 'reflow');
```

One of them shows up as expected. The HTML generated is:

```
<div class="section-container auto" data-section="" data-section-resized="true" style="min-height: 48px;">
```

The other one gets different `data-sections` applied to it, and does not display properly.

```
<div class="section-container auto" data-section="" data-section-small-style="true">
```

Here is a screenshot of the incorrect behaviour: http://imgur.com/9ozNvNC

All of the tabs have `width: 100%` applied to them and overlap (hence why you can only see the 'Help' tab there) and the top of the 'Preview' image is covered by the tabs.

The strange thing is, the HTML is exactly the same, in a Reveal Modal in both cases. The same JS is being applied to each. Does anyone know why one of my sections would get `data-section-resized` while the other gets `data-section-small-size`?

**Edit**: Two things.

1. I forgot to mention, this is Zurb Foundation 4.3.2
2. If I resize the window, it automatically shows up correctly... So I guess if I can run the 'window resize' Zurb code, that would solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem.  After pouring through the issues in Zurb's Github, I found a semi-related issue that was fixed in a recent pull request.

On a whim I merged it into my code, and it fixed the issue.

See here: https://github.com/seantimm/foundation/commit/7af78ddbcc5a516eafed588e7c17d90bee115567